# textField.setText didn't work and eclipse freeze when press the JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have an problem with eclipse window builder,
My code just try to write a text in the text Field when press the button, but whenever I press the button didn't print anything and just freeze.

This is my code :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class B {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    B window = new B();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public B() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnCount = new JButton("count");
        btnCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                textField.setText("Result");    
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCount, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Try clean and re-build.

Comment: Nothing is printed by this code. You mean displayed?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, It didn't worked :/

Comment: @cricket_007, yes I just want to execute this                 textField.setText("Result");

Comment: Nothing here should freeze your code, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: do I need to put this simple code in a separate thread inside the JButton ?

Comment: @Dalya Swing is single threaded and not thread safe, this means that you mustn't perform any long running/blocking tasks within the EDT and you should only modify the UI from within the context of the EDT - without more context, it's impossible to know what suggestion would work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                runCode();




            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

        public void runCode() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            MyDriver.main(null);



        }
```